# How to turn off Interactive mode in FTP (perl)

Tags: regex, perl, scripting, ftp, backup

I am trying to delete a non-empty directory via FTP using a Perl script. In order to do this I first need to remove contents inside this directory and then delete directory.

In FTP you need to disable prompt to do this. Otherwise it will keep asking for confirmation on deleting every file.

```
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode off.
ftp> mdelete 2013-10-01-full/*
ftp> rmdir 2013-10-01-full
```

How can I turn `prompt` off in Perl. There is no such feature listed in [`Net::FTP`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html). I even tried `$ftp->prompt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Net::FTP documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html):

> rmdir ( DIR [, RECURSE ]) Remove the directory with the name DIR . If
>   RECURSE is true then rmdir will attempt to delete everything inside
>   the directory.

You don't need to worry about the `prompt` thing. Just use `$ftp->rmdir($dir, 1)` and it will delete the dir including everything in it.